# What JSON key naming was better?

Tags: json

We know some word is acronyms, the following is:

- Global Positioning System --> GPS
- Hypertext Transfer Protocol --> HTTP
- Identity --> ID
- Uniform Resource Locator --> URL

so, what json key naming is better?

```
{
    "eg1": {
        "GPSData": "",
        "videoURL": "",
        "HTTPURL": "",
        "ID": ""
    },
    "eg2": {
        "gpsData": "",
        "videoUrl": "",
        "httpUrl": "",
        "id": ""
    }
}
```

Comment: This is completely subjective. Choose whatever makes sense and looks right to you.

Comment: It depends upon you and your project's standards.